# Writing object to a file using THIS pointer in c++

Tags: c++, oop, object, fstream, ofstream

So i have this code, in which there is a class of Car which has a member function called as save, which save the object into a file using THIS pointer. I also have main function in which i'm writing the Car object to another file, but the object remains same, however when open the both saved files in notepad they seem different why??...

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Car
{
private:
  string name;
  int model;
  int numwheels;
public:
  Car()
  {
    name = "No Name";
    model = 0;
    numwheels = 0;
  }
  void save()
  {
    ofstream ofs;

    ofs.open("filename.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    ofs.write((char*)this, sizeof(this));
  }
};

int main()
{
  Car car;

  //writing object...
  car.save();

  ofstream ofs;

  ofs.open("filename1.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
  ofs.write((char*)&car, sizeof(car));
}
```

This link has a image in which results are shown....

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAyxu.png

Comment: actually i have figured out the problem. There was a problem with sizeof(this) statement, it was returning the size of pointer in which the object was stored, but changing it to sizeof(Car) will return the size of object...

Comment: "actually i have figured out the problem" Have you? Changing the argument of sizeof will not make either version correct. It will replace junk data with different junk data. **You cannot use `write` with this object**.

Comment: Look for serialization in C++. You should find plenty resources to learn from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(this)` is a size of the pointer `Car*`, that is 4 or 8 depending on 32bit or 64bit platform. Thus you output first 4 or 8 bytes of the object memory, you can see it in your image. To get the object size you should use `sizeof(*this)` or `sizeof(Car)`.